# Infix notation : evaluation of a string using in java

Tags: data-structures

can you help me with my little problem? I'm a bit confused 'bout infix notations . My teacher ask me to implement the Data Structure of infix notation of a string using stack , i would like to cite it to understand it easily .

the string is "(June)" , in the stack the open parenthesis is pushed into the stack leaving the string June be , and if it passes through the  closed parenthesis , the open parenthesis will pop , and the output will be a valid string.

can you help me with my problem guys ,sorry i'm just a newbie programmer. and i'm willing to know what are the steps .

Comment: Sorry, but how do you evaluate strings? I don't quite get your example.

Comment: You'll need to explain the problem better. "implement the Data Structure of infix notation" doesn't mean anything. Perhaps you're asking how to parse an infix expression? What is the desired output?